# How to determine the x/y screen location of the blue dot representing your current location in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, ios4

Playing around with MapKit and I'm wondering ...

Is it possible to determine where on the screen (the x and y) the blue dot representing your location sits as you move the map around?

I recognize it starts out in the center of the screen ... but if you start to move the map it sticks with it.

Thanks -wg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `[map convertCoordinate:toPointToView:]` to convert `map.userLocation.location.coordinate` to the coordinate system of a view of your choice.